# Mixture of normals, dependent on past

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-process, autoregressive

I have the following probability model:

$(X_k|\text{PastHistory}_{k-1}, \theta_0,\theta_1,\theta_2) \sim (\pi\cdot N(\theta_1+\theta_0\cdot X_{k-1},1)+(1-\pi)\cdot N(\theta_2+\theta_0\cdot X_{k-1},1))$

and $X_k=0.5X_{k-1}+\epsilon_k$ with $\epsilon_k \sim N(0,1)$

I want to build a function that gives a sample of size n, from the mixture.

I've tried something like this in Mathematica:

```
  Sample[n_] := Module[{lst},
    lst = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/(1 - 0.5^2)]]};
    element = 1;
    While[element <= n,
      AppendTo[lst, 
        RandomVariate[
          TransformedDistribution[
           p*X1 + (1 - p) X2, {
           X1 \[Distributed] 
           NormalDistribution[ θ1 + θ0*lst[[element]], 1], 
           X2 \[Distributed] 
           NormalDistribution[ θ2 + θ0*lst[[element]], 1]
        }]]];
     element = element + 1;
    ];
   lst
   ];
```

Is this correct?

Many thanks for any help. ;)

Comment: I think I'm missing something, because it looks like you are giving two different ways of constructing the series $X_k$ (and they lead to different results): the method before the "and" and the method after it.  You cannot do both at the same time!  Which one do you want to implement?

Comment: You're right. I want to implement the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write

$$X_k = \theta_0 X_{k-1} + \theta_1 U_{k-1} + \theta_2 (1 - U_{k-1}) + Z_{k-1}$$

where $U_i$ are iid Bernoulli$(\pi)$ variables and $Z_i$ are iid Normal$(0,1)$ variables.  This form of expression allows us to capitalize on vectorized methods of generating large lists of random variates at once, thereby obtaining $(U_i)$ and $(Z_i)$ quickly and from them the vector $Y = \theta_1 U + \theta_2 (1-U) + Z.$  All that remains is to compute the $X_k$ iteratively, which in *Mathematica*-speak is a "fold" of the bivariate function

$$f(X, Y) = \theta_0 X + Y.$$

That leads directly to code like the following, whose arguments are the length of the simulated process $n$, the vector of parameters $(\theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2),$ the Bernoulli parameter $\pi$ (here written $p$), and the starting value $x_0$:

```mathematica
simulate[n_, {θ0_, θ1_, θ2_}, p_: 0.5, x0_: 0] := 
 With[
  {u = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], n],
   z = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]}, 
  FoldList[θ0 #1 + #2 &, x0, θ1 u + θ2 (1 - u) + z]
  ]
```

To test it, consider the process with no autocorrelation and widely separated means in the mixture:

```mathematica
n = 10^7;
AbsoluteTiming[sim = simulate[n, {0, -3, 3}, 1/3];]
```

> {6.02823, Null}

That's 1.6 million values per second--not too bad.  Let's look at some of these values; I plot every hundredth one in order to keep the plot visually recognizable:

```mathematica
ListPlot[sim[[1 ;; n ;; 100]], DataRange -> {1, n}]
```

[image: Figure]

```mathematica
Histogram[sim, {1/2}]
```

[image]

As intended, one-third ($p$) of the values are near $\theta_1=-3$ and the remaining two-thirds are near $\theta_2=3.$

---

#### Update

For `R` users, here is an `R` equivalent implementation.

```R
simulate <- function(n, theta, p = 1/2, x0 = 0) {
  eps <- rnorm(n) + sample(theta[2:3], n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1 - p))
  x <- c(x0, rep(NA_real_, n))
  for (i in seq_along(z)) x[i + 1] <- theta[1] * x[i] + eps[i]
  z
}
```

The timing is even better:

```R
n <- 10^7
system.time(sim <- simulate(n, c(0, -3, 3), 1/3))
```

> ```
> user  system elapsed 
> 1.44    0.00    1.72
> ```

That's three times faster than the *Mathematica* version.